# What is the Latin translation of "don't let a log get under your skin"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

By "log", I mean a literal piece of tree, at least a foot long and too big to pick up with just one hand. By "get under your skin" I mean making you angry like trolls like to do.

I guess it would start with "Caudex non ...."

I remember the word "caudex" from Latin-class as used for both "log" and "stupid person".

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for making your first post! Did you want something like literal "log of wood" in size, or did you want something that was more like a splinter of wood?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a mild allusion here to Matthew 7.3. The word there for the “log” (in one’s own eye) is *trabs*; the splinter in the eye of the other is a *festuca*.

There are a few options for the so-called negative imperative (“don’t”), one I often like is *ne* + perfect subjunctive.

So perhaps

> *Ne acceperis trabem sub cutem tuam*

alternatively

> *Ne siveris* [from *sinere*] *trabem sub cutem inferri tuam*.

Comment: You're translating the idiom *get under one's skin* literally, but I don't think it has the required meaning in Latin.

Comment: Quite possibly not, but that, in a sense, turns the whole question upside down (forget trabs, festuca, whatever). I suppose something like ‘Ne siveris ab hominibus irritari” might work.

Comment: According to the OP, the log should be literal but the subcutaneity metaphorical.